# Not able to compare responseString in objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"the response string is %@",responseString);

if ([responseString isEqualToString:@"No Data Available"] ) 
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message"
                                                    message:@"No data Avilable in  server"delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:
                          @"OK", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

}
```

in my connectiondidfinishloadin delegate method i have the above code. when the server replies there is no data , it does not go into the if loop for some reason. not sure why. any hint will be greatly appreciated.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ResponseString is probably null/nil and runtime knows that that if statement will b false because of this, so skips it. You should see this with your `NSLog(@"the response string is %@",responseString);`

On a side note, [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) is a good debugging tool for this- you can see the http info as it goes out and comes in.

Comment: but my log always says that the responseString is equal to "No Data Available"...does this have anything to do with NSUTF8StringEncoding in the line above the NSLOG.

Comment: Are you definitely hitting the webservice? Charles can help you answer this.

Comment: Hi Luke .. the response is definitely "No Data Available" , i can provide you the screen shot from charles....by the its a very nice tool.

Comment: Try making a simple post..to say google, you should get the html back. If you can do this then the issue might be with the web service.